# How can i colorate one specific state with React-simple-maps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, maps, react-simple-maps

I found this json that helped me to show the map in my application. But now i want that , for example, the Italian states are color blue. Can someone help me please?

```
import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale";
import { ComposableMap, Geographies, Geography } from "react-simple-maps";
// url to a valid topojson file
const geoUrl =
"https://run.mocky.io/v3/3aa57d13-9ec8-4d82-87f1-3f73580db0b2";
 const colorScale = scaleLinear()
 .domain([0.29, 0.68])
 .range(["#ffedea", "#ff5233"]);

export default function HomePage(props) {
  <div class="box"> 
        <div className = {styles.map}>
        <div>

<ComposableMap>
  <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
    {({ geographies }) =>
      geographies.map((geo) => (
        <Geography key={geo.rsmKey} geography={geo} />
      ))
    }
  </Geographies>
</ComposableMap>

</div>
  );
}
```